# ngOnInit and data binding not working in ModalView NativeScript Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am searching sincerely since 2 days and trying to fix that problem due to lack of knowledge. I have started Nativescript recently and I am intermediate with Angular.

## Problem

- I am trying to open the modal `ShopInfosComponent` in my `map.component.ts` :

```
const options: ModalDialogOptions = {
      viewContainerRef: this.viewContainerRef,
      fullscreen: false,
      context: {},
    };

    this.modalService.showModal(ShopInfosComponent, options);
```

`ShopInfosComponent` belongs to the `BrowseModule` where I understand that I need to add it to

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NativeScriptCommonModule,
        BrowseRoutingModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        BrowseComponent,
        MapComponent,
        ShopInfosComponent
    ],
    entryComponents: [ShopInfosComponent]
})
```

BrowseModule belongs to the upper Module `AppModule`.

## Real Problem :

The modal `ShopInfosComponent` successfully opens as intented, but there is **no data binding**, actually **`ngOnInit` is not called** (unlike the constructor).

This is the content of the modal `shop-infos.component.html`:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label [text]="result"></Label>
    <Label text="Static Text"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

## What I've tried

I've tried to open a modal directly inside `AppModule` with the `app.component.ts`, which weirdly works !
It's only not working when putting inside another module which is imported by `AppModule`.

The app template used is the [Navigation Drawer](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/tns-template-drawer-navigation-ng) from Nativescript.

Maybe it's a problem with the lazy loading app routing ?

I've uploaded the app graphic documentation and source code on my website : https://luiswillnat.eu/stack/nativescript/databinding/

Please feel free to use, I am really willing to find the solution and to learn from it.

[image]

Comment: Try running changeDetection manaually (work-around). This might be helpful to get an idea of what is happening. https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1014#issuecomment-441287275

Comment: I have seen that discussion, seems to come from there, the code works finally, thanks a a lot :D !

Answer (score 1):

As @Lasanga Guruge mentionned in the comments, it's a [current issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1014#issuecomment-441287275) of `nativescript-angular`.

Current work around to have data binding and ngOnInit in the modal view is to detect changes manually.

```
setTimeout(() => {
   this.zone.run(() => this.result = "WORKING")
});
```

or

```
setTimeout(() => {
   this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
});
```

are the workarounds for the moment.